# Does setting read-only indices improve elasticsearch performances?

Tags: database, performance, elasticsearch

The title says it all. I have daily indices rolling in through logstash, I was wondering if setting the old indices to read-only would make the cluster go faster in general? 
I am using ES 6.

A small explanation why would be appreciated (if you have time of course)

Answer (score 0):

Setting readonly is more for immutability . It was not introduced for performance reasons.

[Elastic Thread - which created this feature](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/open-index-in-readonly-mode/5794)